# Why is ORM creating duplicate joins?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've built the following query:

```
query = session.query(MatchesATP.ID_M, TournamentsATP.NAME_T)
query = query.join(MatchesATP).join(TournamentsATP).limit(10)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias:
```

Apparently SQLAlchemy is converting the ORM query to the following SQL:

```
SELECT belgarath.matches_atp.`ID_M` AS `belgarath_matches_atp_ID_M`, oncourt.tours_atp.`NAME_T` AS `oncourt_tours_atp_NAME_T`
FROM oncourt.tours_atp INNER JOIN belgarath.matches_atp ON oncourt.tours_atp.`ID_T` = belgarath.matches_atp.`ID_T_M` INNER JOIN oncourt.tours_atp ON oncourt.tours_atp.`ID_T` = belgarath.matches_atp.`ID_T_M`
```

Hence the error...

Why is it joining twice?

Full code:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker()
Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/")

Base.metadata.reflect(engine, schema="belgarath")
Base.metadata.reflect(engine, schema="oncourt")
Base.metadata.bind = engine

session = Session()


class MatchesATP(Base):
    __tablename__ = "matches_atp"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "belgarath",
                      "extend_existing": True}

    ID_M = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ID_T_M = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("oncourt.tours_atp.ID_T"))


class TournamentsATP(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tours_atp"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "oncourt",
                      "extend_existing": True}

    ID_T = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    NAME_T = Column(String(255))


query = session.query(MatchesATP.ID_M, TournamentsATP.NAME_T)
query = query.join(MatchesATP).join(TournamentsATP).limit(10)
print(query.statement)
print([result for result in query])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `.select_from()` and `.join()`. You're telling the query to perform two joins, but not where to start from. So SQLAlchemy implicitly does that by selecting from the first element in your select clause. In this case, you're joining to both tables, so it probably doesn't know what to do. To get the following SQL

```sql
SELECT
  belgarath.matches_atp.`ID_M` AS `belgarath_matches_atp_ID_M`,
  oncourt.tours_atp.`NAME_T` AS `oncourt_tours_atp_NAME_T`
FROM oncourt.tours_atp
INNER JOIN belgarath.matches_atp ON oncourt.tours_atp.`ID_T` = belgarath.matches_atp.`ID_T_M`
LIMIT 10
```

Use the following code instead:

```py
query = session.query(MatchesATP.ID_M, TournamentsATP.NAME_T)
query = query.select_from(MatchesATP).join(TournamentsATP).limit(10)
```

or even

```py
query = session.query(MatchesATP.ID_M, TournamentsATP.NAME_T)
query = query.join(TournamentsATP).limit(10)
```

Comment: This makes total sense now you've pointed it out, thank you. Annoyingly I had got the 'two join' statement from the "Essential SQLAlchemy" book...

Comment: One related question... ```query.join(TournamentsATP).limit(10)``` that's only needed because of the foreign key presumably?

Comment: I don't understand your second question, could you clarify it a little? The join is needed because you want the two tables joined of course. If you don't specify them, you get a Cartesian product or (CROSS JOIN) [https://cdn.sqltutorial.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/SQL-CROSS-JOIN.png] which gets out of hand very very quickly and can overwhelm databases.

Comment: I meant that ```query.join(TournamentsATP).limit(10)``` from the final point in your answer doesn't have a reference to ```MatchesATP``` so how did it know to join the two tables together?

Comment: SQLAlchemy looks at the table of the first column (which is `MatchesATP`) and chooses that as the starting point of the query. That is why the second and last code blocks are equivalent - they do exactly the same thing